# Google App Engine - Cron Keep-Alive Limitation

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, limit

I'm using gae for a project and I have a cron script to keep it alive so that the handful of users I have so far wont have to wait +5 sec on their first query.

Does anyone know if Google will enforce some limit on my app if the logs reflect that there are significantly more hits from the cron script than actuall users?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if Google would enforce a limit or not.

Instead of using a cron job, you can [set the min idle instances to 1(or more)](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/performancesettings#Setting_the_Number_of_Idle_Instances) if you're worried about response time. 
Enable billing to do this.

Comment: will that cost me money even if the actual usage is low?

Comment: You have 28 free instance hours, so it depends what the other code is doing. If there's only lightweight work happening, I'd say it won't cost you anything. There is no minimum monthly payment on appengine. Also, it's probably more effecient that running cron every few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

To address the wait time that you are facing, App Engine has a feature called Warmup requests. Warmup requests are a specific type of loading request and their task is to load the application initialisation code into an instance in advance before the standard requests from your users hit the application.

Please look at [Warmup Requests](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig?csw=1#Java_appengine_web_xml_Warmup_requests) documentation and a [tutorial](http://googcloudlabs.appspot.com/codelabexercise9.html).

Comment: I saw this, but I don't think it will work for me. The users need to check for an update when an Android app is opened, so there is no way for me to fire off a warm-up request. I need the sever to respond in milliseconds, not seconds.

Comment: @romin, as far as I'm aware, warmup requests are there to speed up the start time of *new* instances when the app is already running. For example, when load increases, appengine sees it needs more instances so it issues warmpup request to startup a new instance.

Comment: Better understand the use cases for using cron vs warmup requests:  https://medium.com/google-cloud/app-engine-resident-instances-and-the-startup-time-problem-8c6587040a80

Answer (score 1):

so far google has no such criteria but better option is enable billing with automatic scaling 
it really helped me to pace my site's speed.

if you are really worried on  pace  increase min idle instance and  decrease pending latencies you can find them  on your dashboard if your app has billing enabled.